# MySQL - How to select records that match all IN values but in 1 or more tables

Tags: mysql

Good day, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I'll first explain my database model:

```
User (user_id, name)
Job (job_id, name)
UserTopJob (user_id, job_id)
UserOtherJob(user_id, job_id)
```

A user can setup his top jobs which he likes best. Those values will be saved into UserTopJob by the user_id and the job_id. The user can set some other jobs he likes into UserOtherJob as well.

Now, what I want to do is query out users that match my job search input.
For example, the search input is job_id 1 and 2.
Now I want to query out the users that match BOTH job_id 1 and job_id 2, but it doesn't matter whether they are in the users top or other jobs, or divided between those two tables.

So a user must be returned if:

- Both job_id 1 & 2 are in top jobs
- Both job_id 1 & 2 are in the other jobs
- They have both job_id 1 and 2 but in different tables

The number of input ids can grow and does not have a limit. It must always match ALL input values.
Edit: So, for example if I'm putting job_ids 1 and 2 and 3 into the query, the ids 1 AND 2 AND 3 need to be in the top or other table for that user.

Can anybody please help me create a MySQL-query that can do this and doesn't put too much pressure on db-performance?

Thanks in advance for helping me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this was a brain buster this evening. Toying around with this for some time I came up with this and it seems to work.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(matched) AS totalMatched FROM
(
    SELECT uoj.user_id, COUNT(uoj.job_id) AS matched FROM userOtherJob AS uoj 
    INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = uoj.user_id
    WHERE uoj.job_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY u.user_id

UNION ALL

    SELECT utj.user_id, COUNT(utj.job_id) AS matched FROM userTopJob AS utj 
    INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = utj.user_id
    WHERE utj.job_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY u.user_id
) AS t

GROUP BY user_id
HAVING totalMatched = 2
```

This query counts the matches in the 'other' table, after that the matches in the 'top' table, and sums the totals of both tables. So, the total number of matches (combined from top and other) must be the same value as the number of jobs we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` for this type of work.

```
SELECT user_id AS user FROM UserTopJob where job_id in {job_ids}
UNION
SELECT user_id AS user FROM UserOtherJob where job_id in {job_ids};
```

Comment: Hi Aminul, this would not fix my problem as IN matches 1 or more values passed. It must always match ALL values passed.

Comment: i think it would be better it you create an array with all the values are passed, so then where.. in.. will find the rows.

Comment: Yes, that will match ANY job since IN checks for 1 OR 2. But I need to match ALL values 1 AND 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `JOIN` between the tables to get the required result like

```
select u.name as user_name,
j.name as job_name
from `user` u
INNER join usertopjob utj on u.user_id = utj.user_id
inner join userotherjob uoj on u.user_id = uoj.user_id
inner join job j on j.job_id = utj.job_id or j.job_id = uoj.job_id 
where j.job_id in (1,2);
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your suggestion. But this doesn't match ALL jobs. It will match job 1 and 2, but if for example I add job 3 - which isn't in the top or other jobs - to the IN condition, the user will still be selected since it matches 1 or 2 or 3. But I need it to match 1 AND 2 AND 3

Comment: In such case do a `INNER JOIN` instead to get only match result. In query, replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not make any difference because the IN still works with (1,2,3), and 3 not being in top or other jobs. Because 1 OR 2 (OR 3 - but it isn't in there) matches, the user is still selected.

Comment: See edit in answer. What I meant is doing a inner join with job table as well. should be fine now.

Comment: Try Rimas SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb558/2 and try to add a non-existing job_id to the IN, for example 999. It still returns the user but 999 isn't in any of those 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM User u
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM User u0
      JOIN Job j ON j.job_id IN (1,2) -- or other list of job ids
      LEFT JOIN UserTopJob utj ON utj.user_id = u0.user_id AND utj.job_id = j.job_id
      LEFT JOIN UserOtherJob uoj ON uoj.user_id = u0.user_id AND uoj.job_id = j.job_id
      WHERE u0.user_id = u.user_id
        AND utj.job_id IS NULL
        AND uoj.job_id IS NULL
  )
```

Test in on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb558/2)

Comment: Hi Rimas, thanks for your example, but if I add for example job 999 to the IN-condition, the user still is returned because it matches 1 or 2, but not 1 AND 2 AND 999. I need it to match all values.

Comment: The `job_id` which you add to the IN-condition must exists in the `Job` table - this is requirement for this query to work correctly.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but even when I add an existing job_id it still doesn't match all the values. Probably because the IN does an OR-check on the values, but I guess I need an AND check. So the query returns the users that match all jobs. Not at least 1.

Comment: See at SQL Fiddle example: query returns users 1,2 because each has both jobs 1 & 2; and query don't return users 3 and 4, because user 3 has only job 1 and user 4 has only job 2; so whats wrong?